# beginner jquery, invalid parameter or arguement

Tags: jquery

can anyone give me an idea why this code wouldn't work

```
<script>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".colorDiv").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).attr(border, "2px");
        $(this).attr(border-style, "solid");
        $(this).attr(border-color, "#2F4F4F");
    });
});
```

I'm trying to get a div to have a highlighted border on hover, this is my first experience of jquery and am not sure what I'm doing wrong. the debug says invalid argument, I am a bit unsure how the this parameter works.

any advise would be great.

Answer (score 3):

hyphens are invalid here

```
$(this).attr(border-style, "solid");
```

unless it's quoted

```
$(this).attr('border-style', "solid");
```

same goes for the color, and you could also camelCase it  if you use a object.

```
$(this).attr({borderColor : "#2F4F4F"});
```

also, you're setting styles

```
$(".colorDiv").mouseover(function(){
     $(this).css("border", "2px");
     $(this).css("border-style", "solid");
     $(this).css("border-color", "#2F4F4F");
});
```

as a sidenote, everything is chainable in jQuery, and many methods accept objects, and CSS has shorthands, which jQuery will accept

```
$(".colorDiv").mouseover(function(){
     $(this).css("border", "2px solid #2F4F4F");
});
```

Comment: great that really helped, it was my use of the syntax wasn't it, I'm guessing the error I got was from not quoting the selector. but that sorted it thanks. I think I can carry on then.